# C# How to return an instance of subclass based on the type

Tags: c#, types, subclass

I have the following structure

```
public interface IUser
{
  Guid Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  TUserType GetTypeUser<TUserType>()
        where TUserType : class, IUser;
}

public class UserBase : IUser
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public GetTypeUser<TUserType>()
  {
    // implement something so that based on the given type return the correct subclass
  }
}

public class FullTimeUser : UserBase, IFullTimeUser
{
  public String FullTimeSpecific { get; set;}
}

public class PartTimeUser : UserBase, IPartTimeUser
{
  public String PartTimeSpecific { get; set;}
}
```

How do I implement `GetTypeUser` on the base class so that I would be able to pass in the type of subclass I need so that I get an instance of the correct subclass?

Comment: You don't.  A UserBase instance has only _one_ type, either UserBase, FullTimeUser, or PartTimeUser.  Can you clarify what you're trying to actually achieve?

Comment: Take for example the variable `FullTimerUser ftu = ...`. How should the `PartTimeUser` instance be initialized if someone calls `ftu.GetTypeUser<PartTimeUser>()`?

Comment: You could do that by adding the `new()` constraint but how would that be different from creating an instance the "normal" way? In other words, what's the advantage of doing `var u = userBaseInstance.GetTypeUser<FullTimeUser>();` over `var u = new FullTimeUser();`? Or did you mean that you want to _cast_ the existing instance of UserBase to one of the derived types?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I am trying to inject `IUser` into my methods.

ex: 
`public async Task DropUser(IUser user)
{ 
  var user = user.GetTypeUser<FullTimeUser>();
  user.DoSomething()
}`

Comment: Try adding a sample to your question of how you'd propose calling the method.  It doesn't appear to make much sense.

Comment: @41686d6564  Depending on the type of user, the subclass would be set in my startup class. 
`services.AddSingleton<IFullTimeUser, FullTimeUser>()` and the props would be set when I get the request. Later I am trying to get the correct subclass instance that already got created in the current context. I have separate workflows for full-time vs part-time so I know which subclass I need.